# If clauses not working as expected in Unix

Tags: shell, if-statement, unix

I am struggling with my Unix script to send mail from success.log and failure.log.

With my current script and the changes i am making, either success mail is coming or failure mail is coming
DB_Success_log has all the Database which successfully got processed.
DB_Failure_log has ll the Databases which failed. Below is just skeleton of my script and not exact script.

```
DB_Success_log=path/DB_success.log
DB_Failure_log=path/DB_failure.log
mail_content=path/mail_content.mail


if [-f "$DB_Success_log" ] ; then
echo " From :$from
To : $to
cc : $cc
Subject : $subject

Below Db got success  >$mail_content
cat $DB_Success >>$mail_content

if [-f "$DB_failure_log" ] ; then
echo " From :$from
To : $to
cc : $cc
Subject : $subject

Below DB got failed  >$mail_content
cat $DB_Failure >>$mail_content

cat $mail_content |sendmail -t
```

In the above two only one is running. If out of 10 dbs 5 are failing 5 are success then either only failing mail is coming with the list or success is coming. I tried to change my If clause but it didn't help.

Comment: the idea is to check both the logs file and send mail with failure and success Db name from the log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shell scripting requires you to pay excruciating attention to spaces.

The `[` command is a regular command (as well as a shell built-in); you'll usually find an executable `/bin/[` or `/usr/bin/[` (as well as `/bin/test` or `/usr/bin/test`.  The shell, therefore, only finds the command when it is spelled correctly. Also, when the command name is spelled `[`, it requires its last argument to be `]` (only).

You have:

```
if [-f "$DB_Success_log" ] ; then
```

There most likely isn't a command `/bin/[-f` on your machine; you should be getting a shell error message about 'command `[-f` not found'.  You need:

```
if [ -f "$DB_Success_log" ] ; then
```

I almost automatically removed the space before the semicolon (the shell removes the semicolon anyway before executing the `[` command).  It does no harm, but it isn't needed.

You have the same problem for the `"$DB_failure_log"` — leaving me wondering about the inconsistent capitalization in the variable names, but that's mostly your problem.

You also appear to be missing the proper close double quote for the command starting `echo " From :$from`; that should presumably appear just before the `> $mail_content` line.  You also need to review whether you're missing a first `sendmail` command, and there are sundry other items (`fi` missing, twice?) you should take care of too.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am checking this.

Comment: I'm not sure  "excruciating attention to spaces" is really warranted.  In any language, the expressions "foo bar" and "foobar" are generally distinct.  The problem is more that `[` is viewed as an operator rather than a command, so the character `[` doesn't create a distinct token.  In any case, it is my firm belief that `[` should always be spelled `test`, and (almost?) all of this confusion evaporates.

Comment: Well, I think that novices in shell scripts run foul of spacing a lot — at the start, it is excruciating (`x = y` vs `x=y` or `x= y` or `x =y`?) but … well, it becomes habit very quickly, and then ceases to be excruciating.  I don't spell `[` as `test` very often at all (and even less often as `[[`, but that's a whole separate discussion).  There's also `$(( … ))` vs `$( ( … ))`, and other such fun.